# Download with Webview Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, download

I'm really stuck with an issue. I would like to download a PDF/ZIP formatted file from webview but I can't find any solution/tutorial on the internet, I tried to look webview property class.
i have a webview:

```
WebView x:Name="webviewIntranet" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

and my method:

```
public IntranetPage()
{
   webviewIntranet.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.testme.com"));
           this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

I'm able to show the webpage content but nothing happens when a try to download/click to download some files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebView` can't download file. Microsoft has tried not to be `WebView`, a replacement of IE browser. See the [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/af09043a-61e4-4899-b3c2-303cf0fe5baa/) from MSDN forum.

Answer (score 3):

First of all some reading about what's new in WebView control
http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/07/17/what-s-new-in-webview-in-windows-8-1.aspx

as you can see, WebView hanldes different browser events:
It doesn't support showing nothing else than webpages, but WebView.UnviewableContentIdentified event is fired for them
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.unviewablecontentidentified.aspx

Then you can use file association to throw it to the OS (or do what you need with the file throught the uri... i hope)

```
void webView1_UnviewableContentIdentified(WebView sender, 
    WebViewUnviewableContentIdentifiedEventArgs args)
{
    Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<bool> b = 
    Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(args.Uri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this, but there's quite a bit of manual intervention.  Using something like the [BackgroundDownloader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader.aspx) you can download a file that you have the URI for.  Is you want to also intercept web view navigation, then there's a few workarounds for that; for example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671047/how-do-i-capture-a-navigation-event-in-a-webview-on-windows-8)