# Proxy settings in WebView for Windows 8 Store Apps

Tags: c#, .net, webview, windows-store-apps, http-proxy

I am trying to set a proxy for a WebView for Windows 8 Store apps. It seems that the functionality is not built in yet. I could get the html through a proxy using IWebProxy and HTTP Client and load that into the WebView. However this would only work for when the user specifies a URL. It won't go through a proxy when the user clicks on links.

Now I could intercept when the user has clicked on a link or is leaving a webpage by putting my own javascript in the page: [xaml WebView: How to catch a "OnNavigation" event @Windows Store App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654057/xaml-webview-how-to-catch-a-onnavigation-event-windows-store-app).

But with this method, it seems that I would not be able to see or detect where the user is going.

Another concern of mine is, if I did get the html through a proxy and load it inside the WebView, would the JS and CSS files load without a proxy?

Has anyone else found other ways to tackle this problem? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try the Windows 7 method to manually modify Registry to add a global proxy settings for your system.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819961/en-us

Comment: I'll look into this, thank you! I was hoping it was more of an app level proxy setting instead of global.